# Marinara sauce with too much oregano and tomato paste

Tags: sauce

What could be used to de-oreganate a sauce with too much oregano and tomato paste? I used a store bought sauce to increase the volume of the sauce that I had started with onions, garlic, home grown tomatoes, sugar, wine.

Answer (score 4):

I think your best bet will be to simply increase the volume of the sauce by adding more whole tomatoes... for ease a can of tomatoes of some sort, either whole (peeled), diced, or crushed; or if you prefer, use fresh tomatoes, which will require some more work. Either way, you may want to strain out the seeds if you don't like them.

You may have to increase some of the other flavors, too, but I think the only way you'll balance the oregano/tomato paste flavors is to simply make more of the sauce. You can always freeze it if you don't think you'll be able to use it all.

How much you need will really depend on how much sauce you already have. If it's a single jar of prepared sauce, you'll probably be fine with a small amount like a 14.5 oz can or if you have more, you may need to go with two of them.

Comment: Pretty much the same answer I was about to post. I would add that the OP could use fresh tomatoes as well. Just be sure to stay away from pureé and paste.

Comment: @Cindy Yeah. For some reason, I'm so lazy when I make sauce that I don't think about fresh tomatoes... and if they're already using jarred sauce, I don't know that I'd really want to waste the tomatoes.

Comment: Yeah, me too. Especially if I don't have fresh on hand. But per the post, she started her sauce with fresh so she may have more on hand.